# Maximal $\Bbb Q$ independent subset of $\Bbb R$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given a subset $A$ of $\Bbb R$ that is $\Bbb Q$ linearly independent. I have to prove, given the fact that there exists a well order of $\Bbb R$, that the also exists a *maximal* $\Bbb Q$ independent subset $B$ of $\Bbb R$, i.e. an independent set such that for every $x\in\Bbb R$, if $B\cup\{x\}$ is $\Bbb Q$ independent, then $x\in B$.

On a Wikipedia page about independent sets, it says this property can be proven using Zorn's lemma, which is equivalent to the existence of a well ordering of $\Bbb R$, so I am at least tempted to believe the claim to be true, but I have not (using either the well ordering principle or Zorn's lemma) been able to prove this. Is there a direct way that proves this claim using the well ordering of $\Bbb R$, or is this much easier done via Zorn's lemma, and how would this proof be?

Comment: Zorn's lemma is not equivalent to a well-order on $\mathbb{R}$, it implies it, but not vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a well-order at hand, we can use induction to form $B$: Let $<$ a well order on $\mathbf R$, define by induction for $x \in \mathbf R$: 
$$ B_x := \begin{cases} \bigcup_{y<x} B_y \cup \{x\} & \bigcup_{y<x} B_y \cup \{x\} \text{ is $\mathbf Q$-independent}\\
         \bigcup_{y<x} B_y  &\text{otherwise}
          \end{cases}
$$
Then for each $x$, $B_x$ is a $\mathbf Q$-independent subset of $\mathbf R$ and $B := \bigcup_{x\in \mathbf R} B_x$ is maximal $\mathbf Q$-independent: If $B\cup\{x\}$ is independent, then its subset $\bigcup_{y<x}B_y \cup\{x\}$ is also, hence $x \in B_x \subseteq B$.